# Number format python

Tags: python, number-formatting

I want to have the legend of the plot shown with the value in a list. But what I get is the element index but not the value itself. I dont know how to fix it. I'm referring to the `plt.plot` line. Thanks for the help.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random(1000)
y = np.random.random(1000)
n = len(x)
d_ij = []

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        a = np.sqrt((x[i]-x[j])**2+(y[i]-y[j])**2)
        d_ij.append(a)

epsilon = np.linspace(0.01,1,num=10)
sigma = np.linspace(0.01,1,num=10)

def lj_pot(epsi,sig,d):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(d)):
        a = 4*epsi*((sig/d[i])**12-(sig/d[i])**6)
        result.append(a)

    return result

for i in range(len(epsilon)):
    for j in range(len(sigma)):
        a = epsilon[i]
        b = sigma[j]
        plt.cla()
        plt.ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
        plt.xlim([0, 2])
        plt.plot(sorted(d_ij),lj_pot(epsilon[i],sigma[j],sorted(d_ij)),label = 'epsilon = %d, sigma =%d' %(a,b))
        plt.legend()
        plt.savefig("epsilon_%d_sigma_%d.png" % (i,j))


plt.show()
```

Comment: What is `d_ij`? Also, please include the libraries you are using in your sample code.

Comment: @mapf yes I have editted the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit unpythonic, so I tried to clean it up to the best of my knowledge. `numpy.random.random` and `numpy.random.uniform(0, 1)` [are basically the same](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), however, the latter also allows you to pass the `shape` of the return array that you would like to have, in this case an array with 1000 rows and two columns `(1000, 2)`. I then use some magic to assign the two colums of the return array to `x` and `y` in the same line, respectively.

[`numpy.hypot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html) does as the name suggests and calculates the hypothenuse of `x` and `y`. It can also do that for each entry of arrays with the same size, saving you the for loops, which you should try to aviod in Python since they are pretty slow.

You used `plt` for all your plotting, which is fine as long as you only have one figure, but I would recommend to be as explicit as possible, according to one of Python's key notions:

> explicit is better than implicit.

I recommend you read through [this guide](https://realpython.com/python-matplotlib-guide/), in particular the section called '*Stateful Versus Stateless Approaches*'. I changed your commands accordingly.

It is also very unpythonic to loop over items of a list using the index of the item in the list like you did (`for i in range(len(list)): item = list[i]`). You can just reference the item directly (`for item in list:`).

Lastly I changed your formatted strings to the more convenient *f-strings*. Have a read [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def pot(epsi, sig, d):
    result = 4*epsi*((sig/d)**12 - (sig/d)**6)

    return result


# I am not sure why you would create the independent variable this way,
# maybe you are simulating something. In that case, the code below is
# simpler than your version and should achieve the same.
# x, y = zip(*np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1000, 2)))
# d = np.array(sorted(np.hypot(x, y)))

# If you only want to plot your pot function then creating the value range
# like this is just fine.
d = np.linspace(0.001, 1, 1000)

epsilons = sigmas = np.linspace(0.01, 1, num=10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([0, 2])
ax.set_ylim([-1.5, 1.5])
line = None
for epsilon in epsilons:
    for sigma in sigmas:
        if line is None:
            line = ax.plot(
                d, pot(epsilon, sigma, d),
                label=f'epsilon = {epsilon}, sigma = {sigma}'
            )[0]
            fig.legend()
        else:
            line.set_data(d, pot(epsilon, sigma, d))
        # plt.savefig(f"epsilon_{epsilon}_sigma_{sigma}.png")
        fig.show()
```